# Nest 5.5 Duplicates using BulkAll method

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to index some documents using the BulkAll method like follows:

```
var waitHandle = new CountdownEvent(1);

var bulkAll = _client.BulkAll(elementList, b => b
            .Index(indexName)
            .BackOffRetries(15)
            .BackOffTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(55))
            .RefreshOnCompleted()
            .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
            .Size(500));

bulkAll.Subscribe(observer: new BulkAllObserver(
            onNext: (b) =>
            {
                _logger.Debug("Indexed group of documents");                    
            },
            onError: (e) =>
            {
                _logger.Error(e, e.Message);
                throw e;
            },
            onCompleted: () =>
            {
                waitHandle.Signal();
            }));
waitHandle.Wait();
```

The problem is that once it sends the signal inside the onCompleted event, I have more documents into my index than expected, being the difference a multiplier of the size param, so I assume that it fails trying to index a group of documents, retries the operation and creates some duplicates.

I have tried to debug if there is any error putting a breakpoint inside the onError event, but nothing happens.

Is there any way to avoid those duplicates? Or at least remove them once that I have completed the indexation process?

I create the Elasticsearch client as follows:

```
ConnectionSettings settings;
settings = new ConnectionSettings(
                new StaticConnectionPool(_infrastructureSettings.ElasticServerUrls));

settings.BasicAuthentication(_infrastructureSettings.ElasticsearchUsername, _infrastructureSettings.ElasticsearchPassword);
settings.DisableDirectStreaming();
settings.MaximumRetries(15);
settings.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(4));

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I assume that it fails trying to index a group of documents, retries the operation and creates some duplicates.

`BulkAll` never tries to retry indexing documents that have been successfully indexed.

If each document has an `"id"` property/field, then this will be used as the `"_id"` for the document which would avoid indexing the same document twice, since a subsequent document with the same id will overwrite the existing document.

Comment: the "id" property is autogenerated, as they suggest in their guidelines for performance, so it's maybe generating a new id and not updating the previous document

Comment: It will be generating a new id when indexing a document. But if you'd like to prevent the possibility of indexing the same document twice, you can assign an id to documents.